# Declare array as return type in gen-class method declaration in Clojure

Tags: clojure

How to declare an array in method declaration in gen-class?

```
(ns foo.bar
(:gen-class
 :methods [[parseString [String Object] Object]]))
```

That works fine. But the return type is really an array. How I can declare that so Java can understand it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:gen-class
    :methods [[parseString [String Object] "[Ljava.lang.Object;"]]))
```

Answer (score 4):

I needed a

```
static Number[][] method(int, Number[][]);
```

signature, in a similar way:

```
(:gen-class
:methods [#^{:static true} [method [int "[[Ljava.lang.Number;"] "[[Ljava.lang.Number;"]])
```

seemed to work.