# Clojure's :gen-class and double arrays

Tags: clojure, java-interop, gen-class

I am attempting to :gen-class a fn which takes a 2D array of Doubles as input. I have already seen the post and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398478/declare-array-as-return-type-in-gen-class-method-declaration-in-clojure/2399880#2399880) concerning a similar topic, but I am still unable to produce a working solution.

```
(ns gui.heatmap
  (:gen-class
    :name gui.Heatmap
    :methods [[heat-map2 ["[[D"] org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart]]))

(defn foo [dbl-array]
  ...)
```

I use the `"[[D"` based on using `type` on my input. This compiles fine into a .class file.

Now, when I move to another .clj file, I have the following.

```
(ns ...
  (import (gui.Heatmap)))

(defn bar [args]
  ...
  (.foo
    (into-array
      (vector
        (double-array <list of numbers>)
        (double-array <list of numbers>)
        (double-array <list of numbers>)))))
```

When I call `bar` from the repl, I get the following error:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching field found: heat_map2 for class [[D**

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the object. `(.foo (into-array ...))` vs `(.foo (Heatmap.) (into-array...))`

Note, you should also `require` your `gui.Heatmap` namespace. Otherwise you can get into trouble if the `...` namespace is compiled before `gui.Heatmap`. Then the import fails, because the class is not generated, yet. Adding the `require` will resolve this problem.

**Edit:**

To clarify things.

- fix missing object
- add require
- fix prefix (good catch by dbyrne!)
- fix :import clause (was also wrong)

```
(ns gui.heatmap
  (:gen-class
    :name gui.Heatmap
    :methods [[heat-map2 ["[[D"] org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart]]))

(defn -foo [dbl-array]
  ...)

(ns ...
  (import gui.Heatmap))

(defn bar [args]
  ...
  (.foo
    (Heatmap.)
    (into-array
      (vector
        (double-array )
        (double-array )
        (double-array )))))
```

Comment: If I made `foo` static (so `(defn ^{:static true} -foo ...)`), would I then call `foo` by `(Heatmap/-foo (into-array...))`?

Comment: Well, even without it being static, I am being told that I am unable to resolve the classname Heatmap, despite being able to see that it was generated.

Comment: I updated the example. There was another problem with import clause. I also added dbyrne's fix for the function prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Kotarak's answer is good.  However another problem is that you need to name your function `-foo` instead of `foo`.  Either that or change the `:prefix` inside `:gen-class`.